# ¿Por qué no puedo hacer un setter estático a un atributo estático?

Tags: java, poo, static

Tengo esta clase:

```
package FacturaElectrica;

public class ReciboElectrico {
    private static double gastoDist;
    private double gastoKw;

    public static void setGastoDist(double gastoDist){
        this.gastoDist = gastoDist; //Error de compilación
    }

    public void setGastoKw(double gastoKw) {
        this.gastoKw = gastoKw;
    }

    public double getTotalFactura(double numKw) throws NegativeKilowattsValueException{
        if(numKw < 0)
            throw new NegativeKilowattsValueException();
        else
            return gastoDist+(gastoKw*numKw);
    }
}
```

Pero obtengo un error de compilación con este mensaje:

`'FacturaElectrica.ReciboElectrico.this' cannot be referenced from a static context`

¿Por qué me aparece este error? ¿Se puede arreglar manteniendo el método y el atributo estático?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para que funcione tendrías que quitar el `this`, cambiándolo por el nombre de la clase en sí misma,  porque las propiedades estáticas **no pertenecen a la instancia de la clase**, por tanto el `this` no tiene sentido para modificar una propiedad que realmente no le pertenece a él.

El método debería quedar así:

```
public static void setGastoDist(double gastoDist){
    ReciboElectrico.gastoDist = gastoDist; 
}
```

Vamos a dotar a la clase de un método `toString()` como este:

```
 @Override
 public String toString(){
     return String.format("gastoKw: %.2f, gastoDist: %.2f",gastoKw,gastoDist);
 }
```

Y de un constructor que admita el valor de `gastoKw`:

```
 public ReciboElectrico(double gastoKw) {
     this.gastoKw=gastoKw;
 }
```

Ahora veamos algunas cosas:

```
ReciboElectrico reciboA=new ReciboElectrico(100.10);
ReciboElectrico.setGastoDist(100.90);
```

Como podrás ver, para modificar la propiedad estática no usamos `reciboA` (instancia de la clase), sino `ReciboElectrico` (la clase en sí misma).

Si tú intentas esto:

```
reciboA.setGastoDist(100);
```

Tendrás derecho a una advertencia de parte Java:

> warning: [static] static method should be qualified by type name,
> ReciboElectrico, instead of by an expression

Por lo dicho antes, esa propiedad **no pertenece a `reciboA`** (la instancia de la clase), sino a la clase en sí misma, por lo que para modificarla **también desde fuera de ella** tendrás que hacer esto:

```
ReciboElectrico.gastoDist(100.90);
```

Veamos más cosas que ayuden a entender.

```
ReciboElectrico reciboA=new ReciboElectrico(100.10);
ReciboElectrico.setGastoDist(100.90);
System.out.println(reciboA.toString());
```

**Salida:**

```
gastoKw: 100.10, gastoDist: 100.90
```

Todo OK ahí... Ahora vamos a crear **otra instancia de la clase** a la cual llamaremos `reciboB`  y vamos a imprimirla:

```
ReciboElectrico reciboB=new ReciboElectrico(99.99);
System.out.println(reciboB.toString());
```

**Salida:**

```
gastoKw: 99.99, gastoDist: 100.90
```

Como puedes ver, el valor de `gastoDist` es `100.90`, o sea el valor que ya tenía la clase en sí misma, que establecimos más arriba.

Ahora, vamos a modificar el valor de `gastoDist`:

```
ReciboElectrico.setGastoDist(888.99);
```

Y luego imprimimos lo que hay en cada una de las instancias de la clase:

```
System.out.println(reciboA.toString());
System.out.println(reciboB.toString());
```

**Salida:**

```
gastoKw: 100.10, gastoDist: 888.99
gastoKw: 99.99,  gastoDist: 888.99
```

Ahora, en ambos casos, `gastoDist` tiene el valor `888.99`, porque es independiente de las instancias, pertenece a la clase en sí misma.

#### En conclusión

Esto demuestra que **cuando cambias una propiedad estática en una clase** la misma se cambiará en la clase globalmente, sin importar las instancias de ella que estés usando. Si esto no se entiende, podrías terminar cometiendo errores graves, como pensar que `reciboA` tendrá un `gastoDist` de `100.90`, cuando tendrá uno de `888.99`. Una propiedad estática mal usada podría hacer que termines en la cárcel :).

Answer (score 1):

Las variables `static` pertenecen a la clase y no al objeto, y cuando usas la palabra reservada `this` estas instanciando a un objeto.
La característica principal de este tipo de variables es que se puede acceder directamente con el nombre de la clase sin necesidad de crear un objeto.

```
public static void setGastoDist(double gastoDist){
     ReciboElectrico.gastoDist = gastoDist; 
}
```

Un método static no puede hacer referencia a `this` o `super`.

Answer (score 0):

Seguramente el fallo venga provocado por el uso de 'this' en el método setter, ya que el 'this' lo que implica es la instanciación de un objeto, algo no permitido en métodos estáticos. Prueba a eliminar el 'this' y utiliza como nombre del parámetro del método otro distinto al del atributo.